# MacOSX Snow Leopard on VMWare ESXi

Tags: mac-osx, virtual-machines, vmware-esxi, osx-snow-leopard

Is it possible to run the latest version on osx snow leopard on vmware esxi? I've seen lots of documents on how to install osx snow leopard on vmware fusion and workstation but not on esxi.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's only supported on vSphere 5, which is released in 8 days!

Answer (score 0):

Found a discussion regarding to my question.
http://www.insanelymac.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=216945&st=0

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla out of the box you'll be able to install Mac OS X Snow Leopard Server, for Snow Leopard "Client" you'll need some tricks due to lack of EFI boot on VMWare ESXi